# Waiting for all nested recursive functions to complete asynchronously

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I have a recursive function which calls an asynchronous method, where the results of that method are used as arguments to call the recursive function.

I'm looking for a way to wait for all recursions to complete - but without any 'intermediate' waiting at each level. That is, recursions at all levels should run in parallel, after which a final cleanup action can occur.

I've created a minimal example which roughly matches what I'm trying to achieve.

Imagine I have a family tree API - I fetch my own record, and that returns JSON which may contain a 'parents' element. If it does, I want it to recurse and fetch all parent records, continuing up the tree.

These fetches will all fire off in parallel (with a staggered start) and take an unknown time to all return. However I want to wait until all records have been fetched before I then continue with the 'Cleanup' code.

```js
const recurse = (url) => {
    console.log('Recurse: ', url)
    fetch(url).then((res) => {
      db.write(res.json)
      if ('parents' in res.json) {
        for (let parent of Object.values(res.json.parents)) {
          recurse(parent.URL)
        }
      }
    })
  }
}


const main = () => {
  let data = 'http://api.familytree.example.com/me'
  console.log('Start')
  recurse(data)
  console.log('Cleanup')
}

main()
```

Comment: If each recursive call needs to wait for an async call to continue recursing… I don’t get what you’re asking.

Comment: I don't see any ways to run each async recursive call in parallel, if one calls depends on the previous one, before starting. With that logic, it **has** to wait for the previous call to finish before starting.

Comment: This is an oversimplified example - in reality each iteration may fire off multiple 'child' recursions. While each of these does need the parent to have generated results, so they won't all start at the same time, many will be running in parallel, and importantly I need to wait til all functions have completed before continuing.

Comment: WIth the example [1,2,3,4,5] it's hard to see but it could benefit from some parallelism if it were a more complex branched data structure, with multiple independent branches able to do things at the same time.

Comment: Would a more realistic example of what you are trying to do be something like asynchronously doing breadth first traversal of a tree? E.g., printing out all members of a directory, traversing down a level and repeating? Where each level is done in parallel but then the awaiting is between stepping to a new level?

Comment: `multiple 'child' recursions` - I think if you use Promise.all when there are multiple children you get the rest for free.

Comment: I have updated the example to hopefully give an example closer to what I'm actually doing.

Comment: Can you clarify the nature of `res.json.parents` please.  Is it an array?  Your code example `for (let parent in res.json.parents) {recurse(parent.URL)}` contains a bug, `parent` is a key or index and doesnt have a url property.   Maybe you meant for...of?  It also makes me wonder if res.json.parents is an object.

Comment: My bad - it's objects all the way down, so should have been `let parent of Object.values(res.json.parents)` or similar. I'll try to fix it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion with promises can be tricky, but `async`/`await` will make it much easier. Here is an example of using recursion with async functions:

```js
const recurse = async (url) => {
  console.log('Recurse: ', url)
  const personData = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
  const results = [personData];
  if ('parents' in personData) {
    const parentCalls = [];
    for (let parent of personData.parents) {
      parentCalls.push(recurse(parent.URL).then(ancestors => results.push(...ancestors)));
    }
    await Promise.all(parentCalls);
  }
  
  return results;
};


const main = async () => {
  console.log('Start')
  const data = await recurse('http://api.familytree.example.com/me');
  db.write(data);
  console.log('Cleanup')
}

main()
```

The fundamental approach is to write a function (`recurse`) that gets the current data and return a list of results. Once you have that then you can modified it to check for any parent data. If there is parent data then call `recurse` for each of the parents and add the resulting list to the current list of results. The root call will return an array with every item in there.

Some other things to think about:

- Handling duplicates (in this case parents should not duplicate).
- Recursion limits (not required but can be good practice).
- Including relationship data in results (might already be included in response data).

Comment: OP wants the requests to happen in parallel

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Good point, updated based on that idea.

Comment: @James Nice catch, updated.

Comment: Thanks for this - apologies you had to fight with the nonsense json example (now fixed) but your approach highlights *where* to wait with Promise.all which is what I couldn't get my head round. I have most of the 'other things' covered in my code already, but thanks for reminding me to check them!